# C# return string from several string choices

Tags: c#, string

I have this function that have several condition to check about the parameters the function gets. If one condition is met i want to return the string that is in that condition and display it in Main in console application. 
How do i set the function to return the string that met the condition if its not the last string in the function?

this is one of the function code:

```
public string ShowPackageQuantity(double packageBase, double packageHeight)
    {
        BaseData foundBase;
        BaseData baseToSearch = new BaseData(packageBase);

        HeightData foundHeight;
        HeightData heightToSearch = new HeightData(packageHeight);


        bool baseFound = baseTree.Search(baseToSearch, out foundBase);
        if (baseFound)
        {
            bool heightFound = foundBase.HeightTree.Search(heightToSearch, out foundHeight);
            if (heightFound)
            {
                if (foundHeight.Quantity > 0)
                {
                    string packageInfo = string.Format("There are about {0} packages for the base: {1} and height: {2}", foundHeight.Quantity, foundBase.PackageBase, foundHeight.PackageHeight);
                    //return a message with the searched base and height and the quantity of that package.
                }
                else
                {
                    string noPackages = string.Format("There are no packages available for the base: {0} and height: {1}",  foundBase.PackageBase, foundHeight.PackageHeight);
                    //show message that says that there are no packages available.
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string noBasePackages = string.Format("There are no available packages of {0} base available", foundBase.PackageBase);
        }

    }
```

Comment: add `return` + `string line` wherever you want the string to be returned. simple

Comment: Why not just write `return packageInfo` or `return noPackage` respectivle within the appropriate if/else-branches?

Comment: Why don't directly return instead of storing in a variable?

Comment: its still wont compile. its still says "not all code paths return a value". i still need to return something after the last else in the code  but what?

Comment: Either throw an exception indicating that this shouldn´t happen at all or return `null`.

Comment: @Dolev That's because you're not doing anything when `baseFound` is `true` and `heightFound` is `false`.  Execution enters the `if (baseFound)` statement, then skips the `if (heightFound) ` statement.  You need to tell it what to return in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string variable name you will use for the output should be the same.

```
public string ShowPackageQuantity(double packageBase, double packageHeight) {
    String packageInfo = ""

    if (baseFound)
    {
        if (heightFound)
        {
            if (foundHeight.Quantity > 0)
            {
                packageInfo = string.Format("There are about {0} packages for the base: {1} and height: {2}", foundHeight.Quantity, foundBase.PackageBase, foundHeight.PackageHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                packageInfo = string.Format("There are no packages available for the base: {0} and height: {1}",  foundBase.PackageBase, foundHeight.PackageHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        packageInfo = string.Format("There are no available packages of {0} base available", foundBase.PackageBase);
    }

    return packageInfo;
}
```

Comment: it is not necessary the string variable to be the same

Comment: @Nobody, Of course. But since the output type is the same string, it would be better to use only one variable.

Comment: This code will always return "" since the `packageInfo` variables inside your `if else` blocks are all local to those blocks.

Comment: @Chris,Look at the previous comment, only one string variable. Typo mistake.

Answer (score 3):

When you reach the part of the code you want to return the string from you just call `return myString;`